I need to move mouse to show menu contents
Since few weeks I'm facing an odd behavior on some applications on my Ubuntu 23.10.
When clicking on a menu, nothing happens: I need to move the mouse in order to show the actual menu content.
It does not happen on all applications, though.
Some examples where it happens:

KiCad
LibreOffice
Bash (i.e. right-click on the terminal)

And some where it does not happen:

FreeCAD
Firefox
Visual Studio Code

I cannot relate this behavior with a specific update and I don't know what could cause such an issue.
I'm aware this could lead to a blind guess, but perhaps this happened to others (even if I didn't find related questions).
